# cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute xsi:schemaLocation is not allowed to appear in <people> in Java DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxp, saxparseexception

I am attempting to validate my XML using XSD in Java by using DOM validator.
Although, manually, I know that the document is indeed valid, DOM validator shouts back at me and says:

```
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute <xsi:schemaLocation> is not allowed to appear in the element <people>
```

I have made sure that:
`setNamespaceAware()` is set to `true`
The `schemaLanguage` property was set before `schemaSource`
`schemaLanguage` is set to `http://ww.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`
Both the `XSD` and `XML` are in the same folder as the `.java` and `.class` file

### SSCCE

```
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;

public class DOMValidator {
    String xmlInstance = null;
    String xmlSchema = null;


    public static void main(String[] args){
        DOMValidator validator = new DOMValidator();
        validator.validateXML("student.xsd",
                              "helloWorld.xml");
    }

    public void validateXML(String xsd,String xml){
        xmlSchema = xsd;
        xmlInstance = xml;
        beginValidation();
    }

    public void beginValidation(){
        try{
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            factory.setValidating(true);

            factory.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage",
                                 "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
            factory.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaSource",
                                 xmlSchema);

            ErrorHandler errorHandler = new ErrorHandler();

            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            builder.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
            builder.parse(xmlInstance);

            if(errorHandler.errorOccured == true){
                System.out.println("Document is Invalid.");
                System.out.println(errorHandler.ex.getMessage());
            }else{
                System.out.println("Doument is valid");
            }

        }catch(ParserConfigurationException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(SAXException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class ErrorHandler extends DefaultHandler{
        public SAXParseException ex = null;
        public boolean errorOccured = false;

        @Override public void error(SAXParseException ex){
            this.ex = ex;
            errorOccured = true;
        }

        @Override public void fatalError(SAXParseException ex){
            this.ex = ex;
            errorOccured = true;
        }

        @Override public void warning(SAXParseException ex){
            this.ex = ex;
            errorOccured = true;
        }
    }
}
```

### XSD

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3c.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns="http://www.cmu.edu/ns/blank"
        targetNamespace="http://www.cmu.edu/ns/blank"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

### XML

```
<people
    xmlns="http://www.cmu.edu/ns/blank"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3c.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.cmu.edu/ns/blank student.xsd">
```

**How do I resolve this?**

Comment: had similar error, also due to a problem in the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`url

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3c.org/2001/XMLSchema" .....>
```

**and**

```
<people
    xmlns="http://www.cmu.edu/ns/blank"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3c.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"....>
```

The problem is the *c* in the `w3c.org`. DOM parser expects it to be `w3.org` everywhere-- in the XML document, in the XML Schema Document, in the `schemaLanguage` and the `schemaSource` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
factory.setValidating(true);
factory.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage",
                     "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
factory.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaSource",
                     xmlSchema);
```

with this one:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setValidating(false); // we will use schema instead of DTD
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
                                  .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File(xmlSchema));
factory.setSchema(schema);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem. In your XML file, try changing the schemaLocation attribute -

```
<... xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.cmu.edu/ns/blank student.xsd">
```

to -

```
<... xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation= "student.xsd">
```

Worked for me!